# Max. Requests Twitter

Tags: php, xml, api, twitter

I wanted to use the Twitter API to get the friends status list from many users.
How many requests could I request in one moment?

Little another question:
What's faster: XML or JSON with a lot of data with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there is a rate limit of 350 requests per hour when using OAuth.  I believe it's 150 when using Basic Auth which will be deprecated in June.

Comment: I mean not OAuth request. I mean requests like this: http://twitter.com/statuses/friends/bob.xml

Comment: You can make the request as many times as you like until you hit the 350 request limit.  It would be a complete waste of resources to make the request 10 times a second, but nothing is stopping you from doing that, though you would only be able to do it for 35 seconds, then you would have to wait an hour before you could do it again.

Answer (score 0):

The number of requests per hour over REST is irrelevant here as to achieve what you require (tracking the friends of many users I assume) then you need to be using site streams rather than the REST API. This will give you an initial list of friends for a followed user then will stream you updates to that user as any changes happen.